# Unable to open file vcl40.lib in XE5 project. Was fine until I tried to open C++Builder 4

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe5

Awhile back, I imported a C++Builder 4 project into XE5, and it's been working just fine for years.  But yesterday, I tried to open C++Builder 4 for fun (it didn't open), but now my project in XE5 says `unable to open file vcl40.lib`.

I need to stress, the project is in its own new directory where I've been building it for years.  But I think because I tried to open BCB4, it changed something, maybe in the registry? And now, when I build this program with XE5, it has this hiccup.

BTW, I was unable to open the old BCB4 because a message came up that the program couldn't find `vcl40`, if that's any help.

Comment: C++ Builder is a specific IDE belonging to Embarcadero. It's not generic C++. Please tag your question appropriately, so that it gets the attention of people who can answer it. I've corrected the tag, but it would help if you would add one for the specific version of C++ Builder you're using now as well.

Comment: My suspicion is that you've corrupted your .cbproj file. Project files are backward-compatible (you can open an older version is a newer IDE), but not forward-compatible (you can't open a newer version in an older IDE). This is plain common sense - an older IDE cannot know about the changes that have happened to the project file in the years after the older IDE was written. You should restore your project from your version control system.

Comment: C++Builder 4 didn't use `.cproj` files (they didn't exist yet). The only way this issue could happen is if XE5 opened the same `.bpr` project file that BCB4 opened (and consequently modified, since XE5 doesn't use the same library filenames that BCB4 used).  You should never share a single project across multiple IDE versions. Use separate projects instead, one for each IDE version. But you can have the projects share common source files, as needed. In the meantime, if you have a backup of the working project, restore it. Otherwise, you will likely have to start over fresh with a new project.

Comment: Sorry about the tag.
The project for XE5 is in a different directory, only used by XE5.  Also BCC4 never fired up.  An error message came up and never started.  BCC4 has never used this  new directory ever. This project (XE5) has been using the .cproj file.  I did discover in Options-c++ shared options-Library Path I have lots of paths to the old BCC4 directories.  There are paths to Builder4/ObjRepos, Lib, Obj, Bpl.  If I delete these, can I get them back from a backup of my cproj file? I don't know what deleting them will do.  Sorry for the simpleton questions. Some of this is over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: By now it seems likely that your OS installation is damaged.

Perform a clean installation of XE5 (plus any custom extensions) on a clean Windows OS on a new computer.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, the files have not been changed.  Also I tried opening some other projects also derived a long time ago from bcc4, and created a directory for them.  These project files also did not change (original dates).  When I open the projects (they still had .bpr as the project file, When I compile, the first thing to popup is "cant find dclusr.lib" and also after that, "cant find vcljpg.lib".  Doing a search over the entire computer, only dclusr40.lib and vcljpg40.lib exist.  There is no libraries on the computer that match the files without the 40.  Does this help?

Comment: You can compile dclusr.lib yourself. See e.g. http://www.delphigroups.info/3/10/31581.html

Comment: For some reason everything has taken a step backwards.  When I try to start a brand new VCL project in XE5, with absolutely no editing, (just blank form) I get an access violation error (First chance exception at $32474CC2. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x32474cc2: write of address 0x00401006'. Process Project4.exe (38928).  I closed 5 and opened XE10 (10.3) where I had started a new FMX project several months ago.  Well now I get an access error on that project (rtl250.@System@TObject@InheritsFrom$qqrp17System@TMetaClass:
5005FD48 EB02             jmp $5005fd4c)

Comment: disregard the comment about XE10.  But the access violation in a fresh install of XE5 still holds. I need XE5 because I can't migrate the old project I was working on to XE10 because of very old components. But like I said, can't even do a blank form on XE5 now even though I re-installed the whole thing.  I also had the uninstall delete all registry items too when it asked. (the access error occurred after I did only a repair first time which is why I did a full delete and re-install)